# download images & files from a webpage with python

Tags: python

Hi I'm learning how to code & script with python

I have just finished writing a script that finds all images on a webpage and prints the links onto the screen, I'm now trying to get it to download the images that where printed onto the screen to a temp folder within the C: drive `(C:\temp)`.

I'm not sure how to do that though and after trying to search the web i couldn't get anything to work. How can i download the images that i found without changing my code to much?

Answer (score 2):

[`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) for Python 2.7:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(url, absolute_path_for_downloaded_file)
```

[`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) for Python 3:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, absolute_path_for_downloaded_file)
```

Make the following modifications to your code:

1. Somewhere at the top of the script:

   ```
   import os.path # [+] Added line
   import urllib  # [+] Added line
   ```
2. Inside the `getImage` function:

   ```
   print '[+]', str(len(images)), 'Images Found:'

   for img in images:
       print img

   return images  # [+] Added line
   ```
3. Inside the `main` function:

   ```
   # Get the web page
   page = webpage.wget(sys.argv[1])
   # Get the links
   for x in getImage(page): # [+] Modified line
       urllib.urlretrieve(x, os.path.join('C:\\temp', x.split('/')[-1])) # [+] Modified line
   ```

Comment: the script i have comes back with saying it found 12 images
so that would me i would have to put 
`urllib.urlretrieve(url, 'ASf0H.png')` 
and so on for all 12 images it found, is there not away for me to do it without me having to code in every path?

Comment: that gave me an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: here is the full error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\image.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Michel\Desktop\image.py", line 30, in main
    for x in getImage(page):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: that's kinda working, however its only downloading the 1st image found & it's downloading it to the desktop, instead of `C:\temp`
also how would i get it to print out a message if image x didn't download

Comment: it still saving the one file to the desktop and the out is 24 images

Comment: I'm getting about 7 errors, here are the lines 
`line 34`, 
`line 31`
then give a bunch of errors for urllib.py which i haven't touched, they lines are
`line 93`, 
`line 239`, 
`line 207`, 
`line 462`, 
`line 476`